# Proof by contradiction that $ A \triangle B = A \cap B \Rightarrow A = B $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I've written a proof for the folloeing statement: If $ A \triangle B = A \cap B $, then $  A = B $. I think this statement is false, so what's wrong with my proof?

Assume $ A \neq B $, and that $ B \not \subseteq A $, without loss of generality. Therefore, $ \exists x \in B $ such that $ x \notin A $ $ \Rightarrow x \in A \triangle B \land x \notin A \cap B \Rightarrow A \triangle B \neq A \cap B$ - contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct.
Actually $A \Delta B = A \cap B$ implies $A = B = \emptyset$, which is perhaps the reason why it seems wrong to you.

To prove it, the easiest solution (well, according to my taste) is to partition the universe into the 4 subsets defined by $A$, $B$, their complements and intersections. Let's call them $AB, A\overline B, \overline A B,$ and $\overline{AB}$.

Then $A \Delta B = A\overline B \cup \overline A B$ and $A \cap B = AB$. So if $A \Delta B = A \cap B$, the 3 concerned subsets are empty: $AB = A\overline B = \overline A B = \emptyset$.

This implies $A = AB \cup A\overline B = \emptyset$, and same for $B$.

Answer (score 2):

You did not show a contradiction. In fact, you did a [proof by transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_(logic)), thus proving that the statement is correct.